# How can I adjust confidence intervals to account for repeated testing in R?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, lme4, false-positive

I have linear models with a concentration as outcome variable and studygroup as predictor. Time and sex are covariates and a random intercept for each subject should account for the repeated measures.

```
conc1 ~ studygroup + sex +time + (1/subject)
...
conc12 ~ studygroup + sex + time + (1/subject)

(12 models, 12 different metabolites I measure the concentration)

studygroup conc1: est p-value CI
...
studygroup conc12: est p-value CI
```

How can I adjust p-values and CI for multiple testing (I thought of FDR) in R?

Comment: There is no simple "correct" answer to your question: whether a correction is appropriate or not depends both on your study design and the purpose of the testing.  If you are not a statistician, it would be wise to seek advice, if possible.  One possibility based on what you have written so far: is it possible to combine *all* your data in a single model and include a factor for metabolite (and its interactions with `sex` and `time`)?

Comment: I dont think that I can combine them into one model.. I measure different chemicals in two groups and I would like to know which chemicals are altered in the patient group.. this is also why I think I should correct for the fact that we "mass test" 12 chemicals with 12 models.